# Sublime Text 3 find stops at the end of the file

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

If I have a text file:

```
1. foo
2. foo
3. foo
4. foo
```

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> will find the `1.` then `2.` ... and after finding `4.` it'll say "No results".

It used to just jump to  `1.` again. It still does so on my laptop but not when I use my PC.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can get Sublime Text to continue searching from the top of the file again by toggling the "Wrap" behavior. There is a button for this in the Find panel.

[image: find panel with wrap tooltip]

Comment: Wow LOL
I used Sublime for 4 years now and never knew about this
Thank you <3
P.S. now I feel dumb :D